# Word How To Loop Thru A Table On Column 2?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table in a Word document with 3 columns
Using a loop i can see what is in each row
How can i get the value of the current row in Column 2 to show in my message

Here is my code

```
Dim tbl As Word.Table
Dim rngTable As Range

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Set rngTable = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=celTable.Range.Start, End:=celTable.Range.End - 1)

ColIndex = tbl.Columns.Count
RowIndex = tbl.Rows.Count
    
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
For r = 1 To RowIndex - 1

 MsgBox rngTable.Text

Next r
Next
```

Comment: This is now a completely different question and should be asked in its own thread.

Comment: "Does not work" means what exactly?  If you mean it doesn't match that might be because you need to trim off the "end of cell" marker when you pull the cell content - the last two characters need to be removed (you can use Left() and Len() for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
Dim tbl As Table, r As Long

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
    MsgBox tbl.Cell(r, 2).Range.Text
Next r
```